# Why is boosts matrix multiplication slower than mine?

Tags: c++, performance, boost, ublas, boost-ublas

I have implemented one matrix multiplication with `boost::numeric::ublas::matrix` (see [my full, working boost code](https://github.com/MartinThoma/matrix-multiplication/blob/master/C%2B%2B/library-boost.cpp))

```c++
Result result = read ();

boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<int> C;
C = boost::numeric::ublas::prod(result.A, result.B);
```

and another one with the standard algorithm (see [full standard code](https://github.com/MartinThoma/matrix-multiplication/blob/master/C%2B%2B/ikj-algorithm.cpp)):

```c++
vector< vector<int> > ijkalgorithm(vector< vector<int> > A, 
                                    vector< vector<int> > B) {
    int n = A.size();

    // initialise C with 0s
    vector<int> tmp(n, 0);
    vector< vector<int> > C(n, tmp);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return C;
}
```

This is how I test the speed:

```
time boostImplementation.out > boostResult.txt
diff boostResult.txt correctResult.txt

time simpleImplementation.out > simpleResult.txt
diff simpleResult.txt correctResult.txt
```

Both programs read a hard-coded textfile which contains two 2000 x 2000 matrices.
Both programs were compiled with these flags:

```
g++ -std=c++98 -Wall -O3 -g $(PROBLEM).cpp -o $(PROBLEM).out -pedantic
```

I got **15 seconds** for my implementation and over **4 minutes** for the boost-implementation!

edit: After compiling it with

```
g++ -std=c++98 -Wall -pedantic -O3 -D NDEBUG -DBOOST_UBLAS_NDEBUG library-boost.cpp -o library-boost.out
```

I got **28.19 seconds** for the ikj-algorithm and **60.99 seconds** for Boost. So Boost is still considerably slower.

Why is boost so much slower than my implementation?

Comment: The only time reinventing the wheel is a good idea is when you can make a better wheel...

Comment: Boost.uBLAS is meant to be a standard _interface_, not a robust _implementation_, so do not expect it to be fast unless you're using e.g. the LAPACK back-end.

Comment: Boost uBLAS has some optional debug checking that will slow things down.  See this FAQ http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm, and check preprocessor macros BOOST_UBLAS_NDEBUG and NDEBUG

Comment: You ran the boost test first here -- was the data already in the buffer cache or was that the first execution? Or, how many times did you run both tests?

Comment: Though it shouldn't take 4 minutes to read a couple of 2k-by-2k matrices.

Comment: Could you provide the text file you used?

Comment: @Mysticial tricky part is that most people reinventing the wheel are generally convinced that it's better regardless of whether it actually is or not, or else they probably wouldn't be doing it in the first place. :-D

Comment: Why not profile your Boost implementation and see where it's spending its time?

Comment: You should measure the time taken only by the matrix multiplication. That way you'd be avoiding measuring IO operations, which take lots of time.

Comment: @Mysticial: Well, even if it's not better, it might still be worth it if it takes less time than actually *finding* a wheel... :-)

Comment: Could you try out another compiler? On Windows, I get approx 10/1 ratio (time consumption ublas)/(time consumption your STL version) on g++ and 1/2 ratio on MSVC (with boost being faster!) when timing both methods (w/o IO) inside the same program. Which one is performed first seems to have no impact.

Comment: @JesseGood everything is in this GIT-Repository: https://github.com/MartinThoma/matrix-multiplication If you like to read a little bit more about why I tried it: I've made a blogpost about the topic http://martin-thoma.com/matrix-multiplication-python-java-cpp/

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Slower performance of the uBLAS version can be partly explained by debugging features of the latter as was pointed out by TJD.

Here's the time taken by the uBLAS version with debugging on:

```
real    0m19.966s
user    0m19.809s
sys     0m0.112s
```

Here's the time taken by the uBLAS version with debugging off (`-DNDEBUG -DBOOST_UBLAS_NDEBUG` compiler flags added):

```
real    0m7.061s
user    0m6.936s
sys     0m0.096s
```

So with debugging off, uBLAS version is almost 3 times faster.

Remaining performance difference can be explained by quoting the following section of [uBLAS FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) "Why is uBLAS so much slower than (atlas-)BLAS":

> An important design goal of ublas is to be as general as possible.

This generality almost always comes with a cost. In particular the `prod` function template can handle different types of matrices, such as sparse or triangular ones. Fortunately uBLAS provides alternatives optimized for dense matrix multiplication, in particular, [axpy_prod](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/products.htm) and `block_prod`. Here are the results of comparing different methods:

```
ijkalgorithm   prod   axpy_prod  block_prod
   1.335       7.061    1.330       1.278
```

As you can see both `axpy_prod` and `block_prod` are somewhat faster than your implementation. Measuring just the computation time without I/O, removing unnecessary copying and careful choice of the block size for `block_prod` (I used 64) can make the difference more profound.

See also [uBLAS FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) and [Effective uBlas and general code optimization](http://image.diku.dk/shark/sphinx_pages/build/html/rest_sources/tutorials/for_developers/effective_ublas.html).

Comment: Could you run the same test using the version OP provided?

Comment: @mfontanini: Sure, I updated the answer. Note that I used smaller (1000x1000) random matrices so all the times are smaller.

Answer (score 13):

I believe, your compiler doesn't optimize enough. uBLAS code makes heavy use of templates and templates require heavy use of optimizations. I ran your code through MS VC 7.1 compiler in release mode for 1000x1000 matrices, it gives me

`10.064`s for uBLAS

`7.851`s for vector

The difference is still there, but by no means overwhelming. uBLAS's core concept is lazy evaluation, so `prod(A, B)` evaluates results only when needed, e.g. `prod(A, B)(10,100)` will execute in no time, since only that one element will actually be calculated. As such there's actually <s>no dedicated algorithm for whole matrix multiplication which could be optimized</s> (see below). But you could help the library a little, declaring

```
matrix<int, column_major> B;
```

will reduce running time to `4.426`s which beats your function with one hand tied. This declaration makes access to memory more sequential when multiplying matrices, optimizing cache usage.

P.S. Having read uBLAS documentation to the end ;), you should have found out that there's actually a dedicated function to multiply *whole* matrices at once. 2 functions - `axpy_prod` and `opb_prod`. So

```
opb_prod(A, B, C, true);
```

even on unoptimized row_major B matrix executes in `8.091` sec and is on par with your vector algorithm

P.P.S. There's even more optimizations:

```
C = block_prod<matrix<int>, 1024>(A, B);
```

executes in `4.4`s, no matter whether B is column_ or row_ major.
Consider the description: "The function block_prod is designed for **large dense** matrices." Choose specific tools for specific tasks!

Comment: As I already commented, on my machine/compiler combination (VS 9), fully optimizing, the op's boost version actually runs faster than the vector version, when only timing the computation (no IO). From disassembly, I'd guess the vector version could have been inlined/streamlined better by gcc, with for-loop unfolding etc. On the other hand, `vector < vector >` needs several allocations (optimizations possible?), where boost can use one for the whole matrix.

Comment: Both times look large to me, on my machine vector version takes just 1.3 seconds for 1000x1000 random matrix. What machine are you testing on?

Comment: @vitaut, It's a Pentium M 1600 notebook :)

Comment: +1 From my measurements, I now can conclude: using `iterator`s instead of integers + element access is 3x faster on VC9 but not faster on g++(4.6.2). ikj-algorithm applied to boost matrices is slower than `vector`+`iterator`s (6x on MSVC and 10x on gcc) no matter if using iterators or not. `block_prod` is as fast as `vector`+`iterator`s with both compilers. Timing has been made roughly and excludes both IO and allocations.

Answer (score 2):

I created a little website [Matrix-Matrix Product Experiments with uBLAS](http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/test_ublas/index.html).  It's about integrating a new implementation for the matrix-matrix product into uBLAS.  If you already have the boost library it only consists of additional 4 files.  So it is pretty much self-contained.

I would be interested if others could run the simple benchmarks on different machines.

Comment: above link is broken